# How do you change a text variable to an int in PHP?

Tags: php, forms

I have a variable that is definited by a POST call from a form where it is inputed into a text field.  Is there any way to convert this variable to an interger?

From the form:

```
Lenght: <input name="length" value="10" type="text" id="lenght" size="2" />
```

From the php code:

```
$length = $_POST['lenght'];
$url = substr($url, 0, $length);
```

This doesn't seem to work and the only reason why I think it isn't working is because $lenght is defined as text and not an interger.

Comment: $_POST['lenght']; is that an accident?

Comment: I know I mis-spelled length.  I was using IE6 without the built in spell checker.  Don't know how I ever survived...

Comment: A spellchecker won't help you in an IDE while working with variables, though. If you set a variable with the name "lenght" and then try to reference it later as "length" you will come up with adverse results.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Two things:

1. It doesn't work because you misspelled length <-> lenght
2. The correct way to convert a string to an integer is using the function intval.

---

```
$length = intval($_POST['length']);
$url = substr($url, 0, $length);
```

Answer (score 10):

It likely doesn't work because you misspelled length twice, instead of zero or three times.

Comment: I laughed - seen plenty of code like that though. As long as you spell it wrong every time there's no problem right?

Comment: Actually, I count three of each spelling, not counting the text of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be a spelling error in your code: length vs. lenght - that could be your problem right there.

To do an explicit conversion, use the intval() function

```
$length = intval($_POST['length']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the misspellings of 'length' above, there are a few ways to explicitly convert a string into an integer in PHP. Usually this conversion will happen automatically. Take the following code:

```
$numeric_string = '42';
echo ($numeric_string * 2);
```

This will print out "84", as expected. See the reference on [Type-Juggling](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php).

If you KNOW that the string you have is a number (perhaps by checking [is_numeric()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php)) then you can either [cast the variable to an Integer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting)

```
$numeric_string = '42';
$converted_integer = (int) $numeric_string;
// or
$converted_integer = (integer) $numeric_string;
```

or use [intval()](http://www.php.net/intval)

```
$numeric_string = '42';
$converted_integer = intval($numeric_string);
```

An important point to remember about intval() is that it will return a 0 if it can't resolve the string into an Integer. This could (potentially) give you a second way to check for errors (after [is_numeric()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php)), or it could cause unexpected results if you aren't properly insuring that the variable is numeric to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the value you are looking at has a correct representation for the type you want to convert to, you can also use a vanilla type cast operation:

```
$int = (int) "1"; // var_dump($int) => int(1)
$float = (float) "1.2345"; // var_dump($float) => float(1.2345)
```

Beware of incorrect representations of the variable that you are converting though, i.e casting "a random string" to a number might not yield the results you expect. If you are handling user input, you're better of using the above suggested solutions with function calls such as *intval* and *floatval*

Answer (score 0):

That is because the PHP Web Server uses the name tag instead of the id tag. Even though the id is lenght, the ***name tag*** also has to be lenght, or it will malfunction.